# How to disable film grain in Silent Hill 2 on PS2?

Tags: ps2, silent-hill-2

[The PC version has a "noise effect" setting](https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Silent_Hill_2:_Director%27s_Cut#Video_settings), but is the option available on PS2? "Extra options" menu (access by pressing <kbd>L1</kbd> or <kbd>R1</kbd> in the "option" screen) has some additional settings, but more may be unlocked by completing the game:

[image: extra options]

[According to IGN wiki](https://www.ign.com/wikis/silent-hill-2/PS2_Cheats) the game must be completed once to unlock the setting ("screen filter"). As I'd to prefer finish my first playthrough without film grain, does a cheat code exists or is the only way to use a completed save file?

Comment: https://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-Silent-Hill-2-how-to-remove-film-grain?pid=596104#pid596104